# Comma bug in the realscripts package?

Tags: superscripts

I am using TeXLive 2019. A comma in the superscript while using the `realscripts` package appears in the main text instead of the superscript. I have noticed this issue when using `Libertinus Serif` as well as `STIX Two Text`. MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{realscripts}

\newfontfamily\stt{STIX Two Text}

\newfontfamily\ls{Libertinus Serif}

\begin{document}

{\stt test\textsuperscript{a,*}}

{\ls test\textsuperscript{a,*}}

\end{document}
```

Not sure if this is a bug. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated, never use the minimal class for minimal examples, use something standard like article

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `realscripts`, superscripts are realized by doing

```
\addfontfeature{VerticalPosition=Superior}
```

provided the font has the `sups` feature.

How does such a feature work? It essentially provides a table of substitutions:

- if `a` is requested, then the lookup table will point to a different glyph than a normal `a`, appropriate for superscripts;
- if a character is requested that has no entry in the lookup table, the standard glyph is used.

This is precisely what happens in your setup: the fonts don't have a comma in “vertical superior” position.

Comment: Ok thanks. This clears things up. I will use `\textsuperscript*{}` when I need to use commas. Not sure if you are the author of this package, but wouldn't it be better if a fake superscript was used as backup instead of the standard glyph?

Comment: @latex_guy The feature is applied as a whole, not “character by character”.